# array is showing empty not giving any value

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm running function to check input empty but problem is that variable in array not working.

**Here is my code:**

```
$name = $email = $message = $result = "";
function has_presense($input){
    if(empty($input)){
        return $result = ucwords($input) ." is missing!";
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $input = array($name,$email,$message);
    foreach($input as $key => $value){
        if(has_presense($key)){
            $result = $value . "is missing";
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )
```

it's showing empty array what is problem in it.

Comment: Where is form code. your form code have issue. Put your full code (form+php)

Comment: Can you provide the code of form submission ?

Comment: try first echo $name,$email,$message and check your variable value. Is it blank ?

Comment: ok let me check and update the question

Comment: check the method attribute of the form it should be POST

Comment: check the method attribute of the form it should be POST

Comment: @Anant Complete code updated

Comment: it's my complete form code

Comment: why are you guys giving negative point

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaNisar  from where this POST data  like ($_POST['name'];) is coming? We need that code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that name, email, and message are empty.

Try:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

to check if your the PHP is recieving everything.

Answer (score 0):

**Description** Make use of **var_dump($_POST)** or **print_r($_POST)** which will tell you what is in it if the form submission is successfully done.

Comment: $_POST is working fine giving this result `Array ( [name] => [email] => [message] => [send] => )`

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaNisar print_r() shows keys have no value ? am i right

Comment: because i did not yet pass any value inside $_POST

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaNisar first try with passing all the values then tell me